# How do you convey nonverbal utterances?

Tags: creative-writing

Like when you get irritated and say "tch" for example. I'm looking to do this in a 3rd person narrative context.

Comment: Sorry for flopping back to and forth on the answer, I thought I could check multiple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, interjections such as [ugh](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ugh) or [tsk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tsk) are considered words and listed in standard dictionaries such as the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com) or Merriam-Webster (see the linked words).

As they are regular words, you can use them like any other word. You do not have to mark them up in italics or enclose them in quotations marks or anything, just write:

> "Ugh, that's disgusting," John said. Tsk, what a sissy.

---

The English interjection corresponding to the meaning you want to express with "tch" is **tsk**:

> A sound expressing commiseration; an exclamation of disapproval or irritation. ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/207103); paywalled)

Comment: That is, don't do anything special. Just use the interjection as a word.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to treat it as verbal and use what are called [interjections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interjection), words that have no grammatical meaning but convey emotions. So many different words convey these utterances:

- tch
- um
- ugh
- gah
- eh
- huh
- argh

The list can go on and on. Here's just one partial [list of interjections](http://www.vidarholen.net/contents/interjections/).

A possible alternative is to convey it through the way the speech is delivered, such as "He snorted", and "he tutted", but this strikes me as a poor replacement.

Comment: I agree, "He snorted" and "he tutted" - I couldn't think of a good phrase like that that kept the same feel.